# Is it safe to resize a partition with Partition Wizard?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 250GB partition with 195GB of important data (this is not the OS drive) and I want to resize it to 200GB with Partition Wizard (I heard that it's a good software) and make another partition of 50GB. I am not very sure if doing this destroys my data or it remains intact. So, is it safe ? I searched on the Partition Wizard website but I haven't found the answer.

Should I defragment the partition first or the software moves the files automatically ?

I saw that the new partition can be created at the begining of my current partition too, not only at the end (as I thought). That means the bootsector and the file allocation table must be moved to another location. Is this safe ?

And a final question... Is it better to do this from the Partition Wizard boot cd or from the windows application ? I am afraid that doing this from windows will corrupt the files in use (if those exists). So I think it's better from the boot cd.

Comment: General comment: before messing with partitions (with *any* tool), make sure you have **working** backups.

Comment: If I could make a backup I would not have asked this question and try the software directly. But I can't backup 200GB of data, I don't have that free space. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Comment: It was aimed partly at you and partly people with similar questions in general. But the point still remains: [external] storage is relatively cheap. *Running without backups is data loss waiting to happen*. Another general point and not directly squarely at you :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resize it and it's perfectly safe. The partition ramains intact and there are no errors. The program moves the files if it's necessary. You must close all the programs, suspend the antivirus and disable power saving. And of course you must have a UPS to avoid power failures. I used the windows version of the Partition Wizard.

Comment: I am glad you pointed out that "you must have a UPS to avoid power failures", what with power failures happening all the time within a window of 2 mins to adjust your partition. A lot more chance of power failure than losing your data because you didn't have a backup.

Answer (score 4):

Any time you are adjusting partitions is potentially hazardous.

More significantly, any time you have "important data" on a single device, you are one error away from being scrod, regardless of not adjusting partitions. Disks die **all the time.**

I'd suggest you manage to find or buy something to back up your "important data" onto - or accept that it *can't be all that important to you*, really, since you have failed to back it up. Burn it onto DVD-ROMs, buy another disk, rent some cloud space...

It is FAR cheaper to buy 2-3 backup drives than to pay for a "data recovery" company to ATTEMPT (no guarantee of success) to pull your "important data" off a dead drive. Yet people with only a retroactive view of the importance of their data end up doing that all too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the bootable CD to resize partition especially when important files are saved, which is safer and faster.